# Socket.IO stops working on Google Chrome 43.0.2357.65

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, websocket, socket.io, polling

Please, help me!

**After update to last version of Google Chrome (43.0.2357.65) on my website socket.io stops working.**

It sends too many requests and every time create new socket connection.

Screenshot Network of Google Developer Tools of my site: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLXGg.png

But demo example on socket.io website http://socket.io/demos/chat/ works fine.

Screenshot Network for socket.io demo: //i.stack.imgur.com/QWNW2.png

I'm using this code on client:

```
 $.getScript('http://localhost:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js', function () {
   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337/?token=ABCDEF');
 });
```

**In other browsers code works fine, and in google chrome before update it works fine**

Socket.io version 1.3.5

In console i have these debug messages:

```
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open GET: //it.iksys:1337/socket.io/?token=410235d6a03ead4497fa18037e8da5d73133367d&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1432302871093-738 +1ms  
socket.io.js?_=1432302864284:3715 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data null +1ms  
socket.io.js?_=1432302864284:3715 engine.io-client:polling polling got data ok +4ms  
socket.io.js?_=1432302864284:3715 engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "error", data "parser error" +0ms  
socket.io.js?_=1432302864284:3715 engine.io-client:polling polling +1ms  
socket.io.js?_=1432302864284:3715 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr poll +1ms  
socket.io.js?_=1432302864284:3715 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open
```

Comment: it's not new connections, it's polling http requests

Comment: But code stop working for me. And in Node.JS server code each request is new socket (different socket.id), but must be one socket.

Comment: If i understand socket.io correctly, first polling request receives sid parameter (which is socket.id on server) and next polling requests must be created with this sid parameter in query. But every new request creates without sid parameter.

Comment: theres an error on the chrome console?

Comment: No errors in console

Answer (score 2):

I found solution in defining only websocket transport for client:

NodeJS:

```
var options = {};
options.transports = ['websocket'];
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337/?token=ABCDEF', options);
```

Angular 4:

```
 this.socket = io(environment.socketURL, {  upgrade: false, transports: [ 'websocket' ], query: {token: TokenService.token()}});
```

I suppose that this version of Google Chrome has some problems with xhr-polling.

Answer (score 0):

```
// package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
     "socket.io-client": "2.1.1"
   }
}
```

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1245